# Asymptotics of the reciprocal Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

Assuming Riemanns hypothesis, I would like to obtain an upper bound on

$$\left|\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma+it)}\right|$$

for large $t$ and fixed $\sigma$. I believe it should be easy to show that it grows slower than any positive power, perhaps by a good application of the conjecture of Lindelof

$$\zeta\left(\frac12+it\right)=o(t^{\epsilon})~~, |t|\to \infty$$

Any tips or tricks to start this computation would be much appreciated

Comment: Since on RH, the logarithm of zeta is analytic up to the critical line, away from 1 of course, but that doesn't matter here, its asymptotics (see Titchmarsh for example) obviously work for both zeta and its reciprocal and they immediately imply the required asymptotic for the reciprocal of zeta too and more actually.

Comment: See [Titchmarsh p.337](https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/titchmarsh-and-d-r-heath-brown-the-theory-of-the-riemann-zeta-function.pdf) @Conrad that $-\inf_{|t|\le T} \Re( \log \zeta(\sigma+it))$ grows quite the same as $\sup_{|t|\le T} \Re( \log \zeta(\sigma+it))$ doesn't follow directly from analytic-ness of $\log \zeta(s)+\log(s-1)$ or $\Pi(x) = Li(x)+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: It's Theorem 14.2 in Titchmarsh (the link above goes there), p.337 indeed, and then relations 14.2.5, 14.2.6 on page 338 give the required asymptotics of both zeta and its reciprocal on the critical line under RH - and then you get better asymptotics on every vertical line between 1/2 and 1 too; the proof uses Hadamard's 3 Circles Thm same way Backlund's proof about Lindelof vs the number of zeros between T and T+1 does, so essentially the convexity of various norms (sup here) of analytic functions (logarithm of zeta here) on regular geometric figures like circles and lines.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

On the Riemann hypothesis, Theorem 14.2 in Titchmarsh states: For $s=\sigma+it$ and $\epsilon>0$, both
$$\left|\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right|=O\left(\left| t\right|^{\epsilon}\right)$$
$$\left|\zeta(s)\right|=O\left(\left| t\right|^{\epsilon}\right)$$
$\left| t \right| \to \infty$ and $\sigma\geq 1/2$.

Comment: Did you look at the simple proof of [Hadamard 3 circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem#Proof), then all you need is $\log \zeta(s) = O(\log t)$ for $\Re(s) > 1/2+\eta$, $\log \zeta(s) = O(1)$ for $\Re(s) > 1+\eta$ and look at a the circles centered at $1+\eta+\eta_2+it$. To extend to $\Re(s) \ge 1/2$ and find how to obtain uniform estimates you'll need more work.

Comment: I meant of course $1/\zeta(s)$ is not $O(|t|^\epsilon)$ on $\Re(s) = 1/2$ so the uniform estimates are only for $|\zeta(s)|$